# Hyperbolic differentiation of $\sinh^{-1}(x/a)$

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

So as the title states I'd like to find the derivative. I've used different methods but upon looking at the formula I noticed a difference between the author's approach and mine.

so

$\frac{d}{dx}\sinh^{-1}(x/a)=$

$\frac{1}{a*\cosh(y)}=$

$\frac{1}{a*\sqrt {\sinh^2(y)+1}}=$

Until now I understand the reasoning, however this next step the author makes little sense to me:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2+x^2}}=$

What happens between these steps?

Many thanks whomever might help me!

Comment: What does $a$ have to do with $\arg\sinh x$?

Comment: I forgot to add the denominator for the function. sorry!

Comment: $x/a=\sinh(y)$, then distribute the $a$ into the square root.

Comment: That's it. Thank you @Ian

Comment: By $\sinh^{-1}(x/a)$ you seem to mean the reciprocal of $\sinh(x/a)$, but the usual meaning of that notation is the arc-hyperbolic-sine which is the inverse function of hyperbolic sine. Which do you actually want? It appears the author wants the second meaning but you want the first.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = \sinh^{-1} (x/a)$, then

$$ \begin{align}
\sinh y &= \frac{x}{a} \\ 
\cosh y \ \frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{a} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{a\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 y}} \\
&= \frac{1}{a\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}}
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple: $\;y=\arg\sinh \dfrac xa\iff \sinh y=\dfrac xa$, so
$$\cosh^2y=1+\sinh^2y=1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}=\frac{x^2+a^2}{a^2},$$
and $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\bigl(\arg\sinh(x/a)\bigr)=\frac{1}{a\sqrt {\cosh y}}=\frac{1}{\not\mkern-2mu  a\,\cfrac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{\not\mkern-2mu a}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $$y= sinh^{-1}(x/a)$$ we get $$sinh^2(y)=(\frac {x}{a})^2$$

Therefore $$\frac{1}{a\sqrt {sinh^2(y)+1}}=  \frac{1}{a\sqrt {(x/a)^2+1}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}}
$$